# how can I solve transcendental equation?

Tags: matlab

I want to solve the given equation in matlab to find the value of beta but getting error. I am posting the code and error below.

Thanks in advance.

```
n1=1.77;
n2=1.45;
d=1e-6;
lambda = 1e-6;
ko = 2*pi/lambda;
A=(ko*n1)^2;
B=(ko*n2)^2;
syms beta;
s = 'sqrt(A-beta^2)*(d/2)*tan(sqrt(A-beta^2)*d/2)=sqrt(beta^2-B)*(d/2)';
solve (s);
```

Error:

```
Error using solve>processString (line 337)
' sqrt(A-beta^2)*(d/2)*tan(sqrt(A-beta^2)*d/2)=sqrt(beta^2-B)*(d/2) ' is not a valid expression or equation.

Error in solve>getEqns (line 267)
   eqns = processString(eqns, v, vc);

Error in solve (line 150)
   [eqns,vars,options] = getEqns(varargin{:});

Error in transcendetal (line 9)
   solve (s);
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this; I get 2 values for `beta` as expected.

Comment: In the Error Message you posted there is a whitespace in front of your equation, maybe this leads to the error?

Comment: @Mailerdaimon: hmm...doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: what are the values and how you eliminate the error ??

Comment: I can confirm the same errors (with different line numbers probably due to a different Matlab version). Running 2013a here.

Comment: All I did was write `clear all`, followed by the code above, and press Ctrl+Enter. Works without problems. So the problem seems to come from elsewhere.

Comment: I've got R2010a here.

Comment: tried with clear all but still same error using matlab R2012a

Comment: As I read the [docs](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/symbolic/solve.html), there shouldn't be any strings for equations here, but I don't know this part of Matlab and I'm now giving up `:-)`.

Comment: Perhaps they deprecated string functions in some version > R2010a, and now *require* you to give input with `symvar`s exclusively.

Comment: same error with symvar s. I think the problem is in the equation writing :(

Comment: Mathematica 9 can't solve this either ("Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."). Do you have any constraints on `beta` (which, by the way, you should rename as it's a common numeric and symbolic function)?

Answer (score 1):

I confirm the following works on R2013a:

```
syms beta A B d

n1=1.77;
n2=1.45;
d=1e-6;
lambda = 1e-6;
ko = 2*pi/lambda;
A=(ko*n1)^2;
B=(ko*n2)^2;

solve ( sqrt(A-beta^2)*(d/2)*tan(sqrt(A-beta^2)*d/2)==sqrt(beta^2-B)*(d/2))
```

However,

```
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.
> In solve at 179
ans =
[ empty sym ]
```

This is odd, because in R2010a with the 'old' syntax you give above, I get

```
ans =
                                                                                                   0
 -(log((A + B - 2*beta^2 + 2*(A - beta^2)^(1/2)*(beta^2 - B)^(1/2)*i)/(A - B))*i)/(A - beta^2)^(1/2)
```

Note that this last solution is complex-valued, which might be some option you have to enable in later versions...I don't know the symbolic math toolbox very well; I still prefer the whiteboard method :p